# Como usar um contador dentro de um HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, contador

É possível fazer isso?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    Map <String,Integer> mapa = new HashMap <String,Integer>();

    mapa.put("45 - Jose"  , ? ); //A "Key" deve ser o numero do Candidato,        
    mapa.put("13 - Maria" , ? ); // e  o "Value" o contador  que vai 
    mapa.put("20 - Pedro" , ? ); // contabilizar os votos,  porem nao sei
    mapa.put("50 - Carol" , ? ); // como criar  o contador aqui.      

    for (Map.Entry <String , Integer> conteudo : mapa.entrySet()){

        System.out.println(conteudo.getKey());

        System.out.printf("Votos = %d \n",conteudo.getValue());
    }

    String key, continuar;

    do{

    System.out.println("\nEm que candidato deseja votar? ");
    key =  in.nextLine();

    if (mapa.containsKey(key)){
        mapa.replace(key, new Integer (?));

        System.out.printf("\nCandidato: %s \nVotos = %d \n", key, mapa.get(key));  
    }else{
        System.err.printf("\nCandidato %s nao encontrado.\n" ,key);
    }

    System.out.println("\nDeseja continuar: (s/n)");
    continuar = in.nextLine();

    }while("s".equalsIgnoreCase(continuar));
```

Comment: Explique qual a dificuldade que está tendo, adicione uma breve descrição do que já fez e sobre o que tentou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para inicializar o contador basta colocar zero, como normalmente faria. Para incrementar tem que pegar o valor atual e já sabe que faz isto com o método `get()` e para colocar o novo valor já sabe que é com `put()`, só precisa juntar os dois, obviamente adicionando um ao valor encontrado antes de gravar o novo, como sempre se faz em qualquer contador. Ou seja, não tem nada que não sabia fazer.

```
import java.util.*;
class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        Map<String,Integer> mapa = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        mapa.put("45 - Jose"  , 0); //A "Key" deve ser o numero do Candidato,        
        mapa.put("13 - Maria" , 0); // e  o "Value" o contador  que vai 
        mapa.put("20 - Pedro" , 0); // contabilizar os votos,  porem nao sei
        mapa.put("50 - Carol" , 0); // como criar  o contador aqui.      
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> conteudo : mapa.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(conteudo.getKey());
            System.out.printf("Votos = %d \n", conteudo.getValue());
        }
        String continuar;
        do {
            System.out.println("\nEm que candidato deseja votar? ");
            String key =  in.nextLine();
            if (mapa.containsKey(key)) {
                mapa.put(key, mapa.get(key) + 1);
                System.out.printf("\nCandidato: %s \nVotos = %d \n", key, mapa.get(key));  
            } else {
                System.err.printf("\nCandidato %s nao encontrado.\n", key);
            }
            System.out.println("\nDeseja continuar: (s/n)");
            continuar = in.nextLine();
        } while ("s".equalsIgnoreCase(continuar));

    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pE0Q4H). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fanvlrqz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/HashMapCounter.java).

Também seria legal manter a consistência na organização do código.

Comment: Ajudou muito era exatamente isso que precisava,  não estava sabendo como criar a logica para implementar o  (+1 do contador), sem criar uma variável.  Sou novo em programação java apenas alguns meses, o que quer dizer com "Também seria legal manter a consistência na organização do código." , devo mudar algo?

Comment: A indentação, alinhamento, espaçamento, cada hora você faz de um jeito. Tem um motivo para usar cada um deles deforma consistente. Não é enfeite, organizar o código ajudar lê-lo mais facilmente e entender mais rápido o que está acontecendo. Por exemplo evitar confundir funções com comandos. Compare o seu código como meu olhando especificamente os espaços.